# Updating template and calling $digest does not trigger $watch with correct parameters - unit tests angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a simple directive which adds or remove `focus` class to element based on directive's `scope` property.

I would like to write 2 tests.

First test verify, that `focus` class is on element when `scope.addFocus` property is set to `'true'`. This test passes.

Then I update compiled template of directive, change the `scope.addFocus` property to `'false'`, trigger `$digest()` and expect, that directive will update element's classes and remove `focus` class. This test fails.

Here is a link to plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/k4PBcCwfivsJsbIEUwGd?p=preview

Any idea, why `$compiledTemplate.attr('add-focus', 'false'); $directiveScope.$digest();` will not update 
update classes as expected?

**Directive code**

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            addFocus: '@'
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {

            scope.$watch(
                function() { return scope.addFocus; },
                function (newValue, oldValue) {

                    if (newValue === 'true') {
                        element.addClass('focus');
                    } else {
                        element.removeClass('focus');
                    }
                },
                false
            );
        }
    };
});
```

**Tests**

```
describe('myApp', function () {

  var $compile, $timeout, $rootScope;
  var $directiveScope;

  var template = '<div my-Directive add-focus="true"></div>';
  var $compiledTemplate;

  beforeEach(function () {
      module('myApp');
  });

  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$compile_, _$timeout_, _$rootScope_) {
          $compile = _$compile_;
          $timeout = _$timeout_;
          $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      }
  ));

  beforeEach(function() {
      $directiveScope = $rootScope.$new();
      $compiledTemplate = $compile(template)($directiveScope);
      $directiveScope.$digest();
  });

  // Test 1
  it('directive is compiled and has focus class', function() {
      console.log('test1', $compiledTemplate[0]);
      expect($compiledTemplate.hasClass('focus')).toBe(true);
  });

  // Test 2
  it('focus class is removed', function() {
      $compiledTemplate.attr('add-focus', 'false');
      $directiveScope.$digest();

      $timeout(function() {
          console.log('test2', $compiledTemplate[0]);
          expect($compiledTemplate.hasClass('focus')).toBe(false);
      }, 0);

      $timeout.flush();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is given and accepted, though it is no good: when you test directive with input - test input, do not change directive scope directly.

and shortest example is:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    $upperScope = $rootScope.$new();
    $upperScope.param = true;
    $compiledTemplate = $compile('<div my-Directive add-focus="{{param}}"></div>')($upperScope);
    $upperScope.$digest();
});

// Test 1
it('directive is compiled and has focus class', function() {
    expect($compiledTemplate.hasClass('focus')).toBe(true);
});

// Test 2
it('focus class is removed', function() {
    $upperScope.param = false; 
    $upperScope.$digest();

    expect($compiledTemplate.hasClass('focus')).toBe(false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated the [Plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/Oxv65IhQBAWCJE0o)

Issue was watcher was not getting called itself. We need to use the isolateScope for same. I created the isolateScope as below :

```
        isolateScope = $compiledTemplate.isolateScope();
```

and toggled the addFocus value in spec to get the watcher triggered

```
        isolateScope.addFocus = false;
```